# Image layering, click on icon without hitting background

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using HTML, CSS, JavaScript in Rails.
My images are stored in my app/assets/images folder.
My audio (for onClick event listener) is stored in my public/audios folder.

I am looking to layer images on top of each other so I can target each individual image to set different JavaScript onClick event listeners, but these images are being rendered with an invisible background? that is interfering with clicking on images it is layered on top of.

Stand-alone, my icons (gif) do not have a background.
Sampling of icons without backgrounds for reference: http://findicons.com/search/gif

To highlight that there is an invisible background to the image,

[the bottom icon, this is the icon highlighted, clicking in the background of the icon (it's highlighted) also initiates the JavaScript onClick event listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ug6m.jpg)

I use the rails command to render the image on my page.

```
<div id="id3">
  <%= image_tag "gif_file.png" %>
</div>
```

My css targeting the div

```
#id3 {
  position:absolute;
}
```

To lessen the amount of text and confusion, I am leaving out code that shows the layering icons on top of each other.

My .js file

```
var soundright = '<audio autoplay="autoplay" src="/audios/hello.wav"></audio>'
var sound = document.getElementById('sound');

var icon = document.getElementById('id3');

$(icon).click(function(){
  $(sound).html(soundright);
});
```

Please advise how I can click on each rendered image that is visibly layered behind each other (JavaScript onClick event listeners added to each individual image) without hitting the invisible background of an image that is layered on top of it.

Eliminating the invisible background is a solution I have not been able to find.

I am trying to make a dartboard by layering images on top of each other and make each parts of the dartboard clickable (onClick event listeners).

EDIT: Just editted my last 3 paragraphs to make it easier to understand

Comment: Thank you guys! Your answers led me to downloading Adobe Fireworks to use its image mapping feature to quickly make image maps that I could assign JS onClick functions to!

I looked into learning about the canvas solution but that will take me much more time to learn I think! I know I'll be getting into that sometime.. if you have any particularly useful guides, please let me know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of eliminating the background and using JS, there is an HTML solution.

Merge your images into one image, and then use [`<map>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) to create an "image map" on it. This means creating [`<area>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp) tags to define the clickable areas, and each area (each image) can set off different JS event listeners.

For a better idea of how to use it, see the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap) that w3schools provides (this is very simple, you can create much more complex ones with other tools):

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
    <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
    <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>
```

There are also many tools out there to create image maps (so you don't have to find coordinates and write them in by hand), such as https://www.image-maps.com/.

Image maps are a really cool solution to address this specific problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior of `<img>` tags. They have a rectangular hitbox, always.

There is a `<map>` tag which would provide the behavior you're looking for (after a bit of configuration), but that's been long since out-of-style.

You'll need to reimagine your solution using HTML5's `<canvas>` or (shudder) Flash.

Heck, you could even use one image with one onClick handler that grabs the mouse coordinates from the `event` parameter (hint: `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`), if you feel like getting messy. :)

Comment: Hey, stop copying! =)

Comment: @jlam55555 haha, 20 second difference... but `<map>`s are old news - HTML5 canvas is the way to go!

Comment: Yeah, maps are old. But I don't know how to do it with `<canvas>`. Can you provide an example?

Comment: `<canvas>` can be a pretty in-depth topic - rgraph's blog has a nice entry regarding polygons and hit regions: http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2012/october/new-html5-canvas-features.html#hit.regions

Comment: @fly: Browser support for hit regions seems rather poor though, at least if https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion#Browser_compatibility is up-to-date.

Comment: @Cbroe Good catch, it would seem that's not even supported in my up-to-date desktop Chrome browser... lame.